# Sort my Sites By Rank (using the Popularity Ranking model) inside my content search web part? what are the factors which affect the Rank

Tags: 2013, search, administration, content-search-web-part, ranking

I am working on a SharePoint on-premises farm. and i have added a content search web-part, which will show sub-sites for my site collection. now inside the sort i chose to sort by Rank as follow:-

[image]

But i am bit confused on what are the factors which affect the sites rank? so which site will be shown first and which site will be shown last ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169065.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Bunzab thanks for the link, but which rank algorithm will be used in my case inside the Search Result WP ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a custom ranking model for the default search results, we recommend that you install the [SharePoint Server 2013 cumulative update package published on August 13, 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2817616/description-of-the-sharepoint-server-2013-cumulative-update-package-sh). This cumulative update includes two new ranking models, one of which is **Search Ranking Model with Two Linear Stages**. If you use a copy of the **Search Ranking Model with Two Linear Stages** as the base model for your custom ranking model, it will be easier to re-tune and customize your ranking model.

---

*You can read more about how to create, deploy and use a custom ranking model in the article [Customizing ranking models to improve relevance in SharePoint 2013](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/customizing-ranking-models-to-improve-relevance-in-sharepoint) on MSDN.*

---

Comment: now i already have this cumulative update installed and i have   `Search Ranking Model with Two Linear Stages.` available inside my web part..  but currently i am using the `Popularity ranking model`.. so what will be the difference in ranking my sites using the `Search Ranking Model with Two Linear Stages` VS using the  `Popularity ranking model`.???